# External DTD markup declaration expected

Tags: xml, dtd, xml-validation

I have a problem with XML validation when I add external DTD validation.
This works normally:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE booklist [
<!ELEMENT booklist (book)*>
<!ELEMENT book (author,title,published?)>
<!ELEMENT author (firstname,lastname)>
<!ELEMENT firstname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT lastname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT published (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST book genre (Science|Fiction) #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST book format (Paperback|Hardcover) "Paperback">
]>
<booklist>
  <book genre="Fiction" format="Paperback">
    <author>
      <firstname>Name</firstname>
      <lastname>Surname</lastname>
    </author>
    <title>Sample</title>
    <published>2020</published>
  </book>
</booklist>
```

When I try to add external dtd declaration, XML copy editor outputs error

> Fatal error at line 1, column 3: markup declaration expected

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE booklist SYSTEM "booklist.dtd">
<booklist>
  <book genre="Fiction" format="Paperback">
    <author>
      <firstname>Name</firstname>
      <lastname>Surname</lastname>
    </author>
    <title>Sample</title>
    <published>2020</published>
  </book>
</booklist>
```

### DTD

```
<!DOCTYPE booklist [
<!ELEMENT booklist (book)*>
<!ELEMENT book (author,title,published?)>
<!ELEMENT author (firstname,lastname)>
<!ELEMENT firstname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT lastname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT published (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST book genre (Science|Fiction) #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST book format (Paperback|Hardcover) "Paperback">
]>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `DOCTYPE` wrapper for your external subset:

### External DTD

```
<!ELEMENT booklist (book)*>
<!ELEMENT book (author,title,published?)>
<!ELEMENT author (firstname,lastname)>
<!ELEMENT firstname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT lastname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT published (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST book genre (Science|Fiction) #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST book format (Paperback|Hardcover) "Paperback">
```